# Prove $ P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B) $

Tags: probability

I'm stuck trying to prove the following proposition: for any events A, B,

$$P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$$

I have the following proposition at hand:

$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)
$$

And, if $A\subset B$ then:

$$
P(B-A)=P(B)-P(A)
$$

But can't figure out how to proceed. Any direction will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the definition of events, we can treat events as sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory)

> Lemma: $A-B=A-(A\cap B)$.

Proof:According to the definition of the difference of two sets, we have 
$$A-B=\{ x \in A \mid x \notin B \}$$ 
and 
$$A-(A\cap B)=\{ x \in A \mid x \notin A\cap B \}.$$

- For any $x\in A-B$, $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. If $x \in A\cap B$, then $x \in B$. It is a contradiction. Thus $x \notin A\cap B$. So $x \in A-(A\cap B)$.
- For any $x \in A-(A\cap B)$, $x\in A$ and $x\notin A\cap B$. Thus $x \notin B$. So $x \in A-B$.

Therefore, $A-B=A-(A\cap B)$. QED.

==================================

Note that $A-B=A-(A\cap B)$ and $(A\cap B)\subset A$. We have 
$$P(A-B)=P(A-A\cap B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B).$$

Comment: Thank you! This will help me for further problems, I see the best approach seems to be using set theory properties and propositions to find identities, and only at last apply the measure of probability. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^{\prime})=P(A)$

Then we have

$P(A\cap B^{\prime})=P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$

Therefore, $P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: you were faster :-)

Comment: PS. The rule noted is the **Law of Total Probability**: The probability measure for a *union of disjoint events* equals the *sum* of the probability measures for those events.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My problem doesn't specifically mention disjoint events, so I'm not sure whether I can use the proposition your demonstration is based on.

Answer (score 1):

$RTP:$ $$P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$$

Just a visual method.Let us say

[image]

Take the region

$Pink+Blue$ as your set $P(A)$

$Green+Blue$ as your set $P(B)$

$Blue$ as your set $P(A\cap B)$

Therefore

$LHS:$  $$P(A-B)$$
$$ Pink$$

$RHS:$ $$P(A)-(A\cap B)$$
       $$ (Pink+Blue)-Blue $$
       $$ Pink $$

Thus $$LHS=RHS=Pink$$

Comment: Thanks for the drawing, it cleared up my mind a bit! I suppose I should've tried with set theory properties before. Will look at them, thanks!